# expex "everylabel=\actualexno" causes error in later references

Tags: expex

I am having problems with numbers of examples. When I refer to the example (by its label) before it actually occurs, the number is correct. But referencing it after it has been defined gives a wrong number.

It happens only when I use the `everylabel=\actualexno` within the `\definestyle` command, and the example is divided into subexamples.

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{expex}
    \definelingstyle{IJAL}{everylabel=\actualexno}  % HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    \lingset{lingstyle=IJAL}                        % (and here)

    \begin{document}
    \gathertags
    Referencing ahead of the definition gives 
      correct number of the whole example (\getref{a}), 
      as well as its part (\getref{a.A}), 
      although the full reference gives us too much (\getfullref{a.A}).

    \pex<a>
      \a<A> some example
    \xe


    The reference to the whole example is still correct afterwards (\getref{a}), 
      but the reference to its part has a one too large prefix (\getref{a.A}) 
      and the full reference is just a concatenation of both, as usual (\getfullref{a.A}).

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `expex` was update on ctan yesterday.  are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, it happens with the current version (which is 5.0b).

Comment: I contacted the package author and it turns out this behaviour is a bug. It will be corrected in future releases (not on ctan yet).